# Gridview adapter causes java.lang.NullPointerException:

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

I am getting a `NullPointerException` MainView

Below is my code :

MainView.java -The class that throws the error

```
    public class MainView extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainview);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

mainview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>
```

ImageView.java

```
     public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    // Keep all Images in array
    public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.ic_btcar, R.drawable.ic_btcar
    };

    // Constructor
    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbIds[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

EDIT: LOGCAT

```
Process: com.***********t.obd, PID: 16766
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cyberscene.hazmat.obd/com.cyberscene.hazmat.obd.reader.activity.MainView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.***********.activity.MainView.onCreate(MainView.java:43)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6500)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3072)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: post your logcat error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Then you got an exception, remember to post a stacktrace, so we could see what happened. From code only, I could say that there is only one place for NPE to be possibly thrown - gridView.setAdapter.

Comment: please post you logcat

Comment: Thanks for the responses. The logcat has been added.

Comment: please look at  at  line 43 in MainView.java

Comment: @bpAFree Line 43 = gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

Comment: i have exceuted the same code that u have posted and itz working fine..no log cat error

Comment: @Shaun your code is working. try to clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: according to this error it is not getting the id of ur griview...check ur layout file once again..and the id of ur gridview...clean and rebuild the project once again and then run ur project

Answer (score 0):

**Try to clean your Project and Re-Build it.**

What I can see in logs

> : Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

is that when setting adapter, your `gridView` is **null**. This might be possible due to problem with reference of **R.java** file.

Comment: I do reference the .R java file, however, when I remove it Android studio give me an error on `GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);`

Comment: @Shaun on Menu select *Project -> Clean...-> check_your_project_name*. and click ok.

Comment: @Shaun also if *Project-->Build Automatically* not selected then select it.

Comment: @arun I am using android 1.3.1, this project has gradle.. There is no project on the menu.

Comment: @shaun sry. That is for eclipse. for android studio. Build > Clean Project or Build > Rebuild Project

Comment: @arun tried that. Doesn't work. Could this be that I have roboguice as a dependency?

Comment: @Shaun can you please check whether your gridview is null or your ImageAdapter? Use like ImageAdapter imageAdp = new ImageAdapter(this); and gridView.setAdapter(imageAdp); check which is null

Comment: @ChintanRathod it seems to be the imageAdapter

Comment: @ChintanRathod Ignore that, erro is thrown on `gridView.setAdapter(adapt);`

Comment: This has worked for me.

    `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        GridView gridView = new GridView(this);
        gridView.setNumColumns(3);
        setContentView(gridView);
        
        ImageAdapter adapt = new ImageAdapter(this);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapt);
    }`